# Wordpress Query - Update Username Where Email Equals

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, telegram

We have like 350 users in our wordpress environment. We'd need to update all these usernames with a Telegram username for some reason.

Is there a sort of query we can write in SQL so that we can update a username when it meets a specific requirement?

Something like:

update wp_users set user_login = '@telegramname' where email = 'john@doe.com' .

I'm stuck at this and don't know how to approach this since it's not 1 user but 350.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get all user and update it according to your requirement.

```
$user_list = $wpdb->get_results('select * from wp_users ORDER BY `ID` DESC');
    foreach ($user_list as $user) { 
        $user_id = $user->ID;  
        user_email =  $user->user_email;
        $content = $post_content[0]->post_content ; 
        $wpdb->query('UPDATE wp_users SET user_login = "@telegramname" WHERE email = "'.$user_email.'"');    
    }
```

Comment: @Mand Is this something that you want? or I'm missing something in it.